# In jquery How to get selected text in select

Tags: jquery, html

How can I get selected text from drop-down list using jQuery, not using the selected value?

Comment: Do you mean you want the text you are displaying in option not the option value?

Comment: Yes, I need displaying text in option not value

Comment: Bhai kahana kya chahte ho?

Comment: bhaiya dropdown ka text select karna hai value nahi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
$("#selectid option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try any of below:

```
    $("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text();
    $("#yourdropdownid option").is("selected").text();
```

Comment: This also works: `$('#yourdropdownid').children("option:selected").text();`

Answer (score 1):

try to use this:
 `$("#dropdownId option:selected").text();`

[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/se7oz6w5/)

Answer (score 1):

do it like this
$("#selectid option:selected").text();